# use python to add two custom datatypes?

Tags: python, class, types, sum

```
class MyInt(object) :

     #  I'm trying to add two custom types (MyInt) together
     #  and have the sum be the same type. (MyInt) 
     #  What am I doing wrong? 

     def __init__(self, x):
       self.x = x

     def __add__(self,other):
       return self.x + other    

a = MyInt(1)

b = MyInt(1)

print a + 1    # ---->  2

print type(a)  # ---->  "class '__main__.MyInt' 

 #c = a + b     #  this won't work 

 #print a + b    #  this won't work
```

Comment: needs to be `return MyInt(self.x + other.x)` ?

Answer (score 5):

There is an error in `__add__`, should be:

```
def __add__(self,other):
   return MyInt(self.x + other.x)
```

Then, you can add `MyInt` instances:

```
a = MyInt(1)
b = MyInt(1)

c = a + b
print type(c)  # prints <class '__main__.MyInt'>
print c.x  # prints 2
```

Note, that `a + 1` won't work since `1` is not a type of `MyInt`. If you want to support it, you'll need to improve your `__add__` method and define how to behave in case of different types of `other` argument.